# Controlling vector opacity in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transparency, sai

I recently moved from Paint Tool SAI to Adobe Illustrator CC 2015. I'm confused on how to control the opacity of the vector.

There's the "Width Tool" to control the width on any point on the vector, but there's no option to control the opacity on any point on the vector.

Is this impossible to do in Illustrator or am I missing something?
Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: I'm talking about making the lines look tapered through transparency to mimic inking, not making the WHOLE vector line more transparent but just a part of it

Comment: Opacity = Transparency. Check Illustrator's online help.

Comment: No there is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Menu/window/Transparency    then in transparency window change there the opacity.[image]